# Styling actionbar tabs - the easy way

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-styles, android-style-tabhost

I'm trying to apply a custom style to the actionbar tabs, but for now without any success. I know there are many tutorials out there, but can someone explain how it should be done or provide a link to a **good** tutorial or documentation on how can I implement custom styling.

Here is the code I have:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB1");
        Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2");
        // Set Tab Listeners
        Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
        Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        // Add tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
```

What Im trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of code I wrote for one of my projects, you should be able to easily adjust it for your own needs!

```
//@param string - the R.string.name_of_string, I use it for convenience
private ActionBar.Tab createCustomTab(ActionBar actionBar, int string){
    View tabView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab, null);

    ((TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.txt_tab)).setText(string);

    //in my case I wanted to center the layout - for some reason certain layout params do not work in the XML,
    //  (such as centering), so I do that here
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    tabView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    return actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(tabView);
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Your code seems to inflate the tabs, but seems the original tabs have somekind of padding - and the original tab design is visible in the background. Take a look here: http://postimg.org/image/94fvypsi7/

Comment: For my solution I used this to change the text styling and add a changeable ImageView in the tab... If you're trying to change the color of the tabs, have you tried follwing [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)?

Comment: Also, if the padding is causing a problem, maybe you could play with the layout paramaters on the tab's parent... (View) tab.getParent()